# Can PHP or mysqli capture equivalent of mysql console responses?

Tags: php, mysql

A simple mysqli Query:

$DoNukePrefsDBC = "DELETE FROM `DB_DiaryOfAnApp`.`ACTVxCJAR` WHERE `REVxGUIDxREF` = '$IdxZero' LIMIT 1";

Variable $IdxZero may or may not have a valid value in that, the ROW may or may not exist.

When it does not, the Query executes and fails silently.

But, I set up a DELETE using a value : {99fa39e9-4f79-4045-8adc-905ca1283c8e} for
a ROW which I KNOW does not exist and put it to the mysql console ::

mysql> DELETE FROM `DB_DiaryOfAnApp`.`ACTVxCJAR` WHERE
`REVxGUIDxREF` = '{99fa39e9-4f79-4045-8adc-905ca1283c8e}' LIMIT 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

My question is this: is there a way to capture [[[  Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)  ]]]
in a php variable, in my script?

Edit:  Ah, some good jumping off points in the answer this question was marked as a duplicate of:

mysqli_affected_rows()
mysqli_info()

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: @AbraCadaver Hunh.  Yes, I can see that would be a fit tool.  Definitely can code something up off that.  Is it the case that this is pretty much the only option?  This question got *closed* in a right hurry.  Can't vote up a comment but for you, lol.  Thx.

Comment: PHP functions wont give you that text if that's what you need.

Comment: Yeap, was hoping there was some obscure built~in; but between exec or some kludgy test if row exists before the query I can work around it. :)